# How to read a text file from multiple thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a program that uses multiple threads (300) to query an API. Currently it is behaving as a crawler, each thread determines its next web API call based on the API call's result it just processed and a random parameter.

I have built a list of parameters that will take the "random parameter" out of the equation and make it more efficient by eliminating the redundant API calls that occured as a result of using that random parameter.

That list is in the form of a text file of approximately 8 million lines.

Ideally what I would like to have is a stream reader object in my main thread that would be thread-safe and that all the (300) other threads would use to "getLine" from the textfile whenever they are done processing the last one until exhaustion of the file.

I am a little lost as to what I should be looking at, any suggestions and answers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean you *actually* have 300 threads in your application? Without reading the rest of the question I can say at once that you're doing something wrong. To answer your question, you should look at [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, and 300 threads happens to be the optimal number of thread in terms of how many pages I am able to scan per minute.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That looks exactly like what I need, the only question is whether I would encounter a problem having 8 million ulongs pushed into that queue?

Comment: @Pi_ You should only add to the queue if it's under X amount of elements, otherwise wait for the reads to remove some items from the queue before continuing to read the file.

Comment: @Matthew That ought to work, I'll have a thread periodically checking for the queue count and reading/pushing new entries into it when it drops below a threshold. Thanks :) if either of you want to add an answer to my question so I can accept it then please do.

Comment: Don't use `ConcurrentQueue` directly. Use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), which provides a much more useful interface to `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: Have you tried multi-process instead? may be easier to implement, and just as fast.

Comment: @jeffo I actually had trouble stirring away from multiprocess. This is a windows form app and having to open more than one is no good.

Answer (score 0):

First way

```
    public static string GetLineThreadSafe(this StreamReader sr)
    {
        lock (sr)
        {
            return sr.EndOfStream ? null : sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Second way

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnumirator(this StreamReader sr)
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            yield return sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessParalel(this StreamReader sr, Action<string> action, int threadsCount)
    {
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadsCount;
        Parallel.ForEach(sr.GetEnumirator(), po, action);
    }
```